# Can you use GQL / Google DataStore outside of google appengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Can I use GQl/DataStore in my local python app? I know I can use them locally when running the dev_appserver.py when writing a webapp but now I don't want to do anything web related and keep it all local with just my normal pythonfile.py with no HTML interfacing. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: why?.... to use the datastore you NEED to use the dev appserver, unless you go in the sdk and figure out how to write your own version of datastore...  But honestly the first question, is WHY?  You can use local files and local database instead of the datastore, which will require HTML

Comment: I think that writing a simple interface on top of something like sqlite is probably better (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).  IIRC, this is how the dev_appserver emulates the production datastore.

Comment: what do you mean "why"? The why is because I've learned to use GQL/DataStore as a nice NOSQL db and as opposed to having to learn something entirely new or write something on top of another library or from scratch it would be nice to be able to use the thing that works great for my needs and I know very well so far, I'd say those are the main reasons

Comment: I mean why as in you're using a tool the wrong way. Yes you can hammer a nail using the handle of a screwdriver, but you are still better off with a hammer.  there are nosql solutions that can be easier used than the datastore, which is meant to be put on a distributed architecture and accessed over the web.  (btw, side note, when answering to a comment, if the post isn't from me, add @Julldar so I get notified :)  )

Comment: @Julldar fair enough, I guess it's time to look into other options. Thanks

Comment: you'll find that performance decreases far quicker then you'd expect once you start to use serious amounts of data in the local development_server.

Answer (score 1):

> The Remote API can also be used within local applications. This  will allow you to write local applications that use App Engine
>   services and access datastore. It is important to note that using the
>   Remote API will incur quota usage on the application you are
>   accessing.
>
> Before beginning, make sure the App Engine SDK is added to your Python
>   path and Remote API is enabled in your App Engine application. The
>   following example shows the use of OAuth 2.0 credentials to configure
>   the Remote API:

```
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from helloworld import helloworld

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth('your_app_id.appspot.com',
                                           '/_ah/remote_api')

# Fetch the most recent 10 guestbook entries
entries = helloworld.Greeting.all().order("-date").fetch(10)
# Create our own guestbook entry
helloworld.Greeting(content="A greeting").put()
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the "actual" answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for that. The answer looks awesome! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Cloud Datastore can be accessed via client libraries outside of App Engine. They run on the v1 API which just went GA (August 16, 2016) after a few years in Beta.

[The Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/client-libraries) are available for Python, Java, Go, Node.js, Ruby, and there is even .NET.

You should be aware that the GQL language variant supported in NDB is a little different from what the Cloud Datastore service itself supports. The NDB Client Library does some of it's own custom parsing that can split certain queries into multiple ones to send to the service, combining the results client-side.

Take a read of our [GQL reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/gql/gql_reference).